# How to use Neglect function in FormCalc?

Tags: feyncalc

I am trying to calculate amplitude from Feynman diagram with FormCalc package and I want to set mass of external particle to be zero which I found that I have to use "Neglect".

However, I can't find how to use this function in the manual. As I tried, it's not an option for CalcFeynAmp function and use this function before CalcFeynAmp also doesn't work.

```
Neglect[MD]=0;
CalcFeynAmp[...];
```

Anyone knows how to use "Neglect"?

Comment: Neglect is described on p. 22 of the FormCalc manual (FC9Guide.pdf).

Comment: @vsht I've looked at that one already but there is no information about where to use this function. So, my problem is I don't know when I have to use this function.